# Ember computed property or observer within a service

Tags: ember.js

I have a service, and declare a property in the service

```
bucket: []
```

Later in the service, I add something to bucket.

I'm trying to set up in this same service an Ember computed property or observer to listen/respond to changes in bucket.

Something like:

```
bucketListener: Ember.computed('bucket', function() {
   //do stuff in response to something being added to or removed from the bucket
}
```

But I can't get this to work. I've tried a lot of different permutations,using Ember.computed and Ember.observer, but I can never get bucketListener to fire.

I have checks in place and am sure that bucket is getting added to as expected or removed from as expected, but bucketListener still isn't getting called into.

Is there some trick to doing this within a service? Or am I just bungling something more basic?

Comment: hmm i thought it would be just `bucket.[]` or `bucket.@each` at least I think that's how it was back in the 1.x days with `.properties` and `.observes`. But I just tried this in a component (not sure if that makes a difference) but that doesn't seem to be working. I'm curious myself now

Comment: @lordofthefobs for setting bucket property, you need to use pushObject instead of push. only then it will trigger computed properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trigger computed properties, you need to use `this.get('bucket').pushObject('something')` instead of usual push().
When you access/use bucketListener only then computed property will be called.

Working example twiddle.https://ember-twiddle.com/776ffb2be7e129655ef62e59b2dc8697?openFiles=services.cart.js%2C

Comment: Are you sure, you are accessing bucketListener..don't forget to return values for computed properties. currently you are not returning anything

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately even when I add a return, it's not calling in. I've got a simple console log statement first thing in bucketListener, and it's definitely not firing.

Comment: Thanks for the jfiddle, appreciate that. Indeed your fiddle is working. I think it's because you are referencing bucketListener in one of your templates, while I'm just trying to use bucketListener as essentially an internal helper. If you remove the bucketListener part of the application.hbs file in your fiddle, the bucketListener stops working.  So maybe my original question has morphed into: is it possible to set up a computed property if the property is not explicitly referenced in a template?

Comment: Sorry, not a computed property, that would not work. But shouldn't an observer still work without requiring a template reference?

Comment: Well, I got it working as an observer. I must just not have been using the right combination of syntax. Using .@each was not working for me, but switching to "bucketListener: Ember.observer('bucket.[]', function() { //do stuff, then make sure to return something" in combination with using pushObject instead of push seems to be doing the trick. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: yes it will work. check twiddle  https://ember-twiddle.com/776ffb2be7e129655ef62e59b2dc8697?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C

Comment: @each -  individual array items change, .[]- items are added to or removed from the array, or if the array property is set to a different array.    .https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/

Answer (score 1):

Service is no different from usual Ember.Object in terms of computed properties or observer. Please use `.[]` to watch for elements being added or removed and observer intead of CP to fire when property changes. You can also watch main property to be sure it will fire:

```
bucketListener: Ember.observer('bucket', 'bucket.[]', function() {
   //do stuff in response to something being added to or removed from the bucket
}
```

Comment: I tried same thing with Ember 2.7 and it wasn't working for me either. I also tried `'bucket', 'bucket.@each'` with no luck